# Integer Solutions for a Multivariable Quadratic

Tags: quadratics

I'm solving a math puzzle and arrived at a quadratic:$$ \frac{6000n}{x(x-n)}=c $$ I only just graduated from high school and have very limited knowledge. I'm wondering if it's possible to find all integer solutions to this equation where $n$ and $c$ are variables, not constants. I know that when $n=3$ and $c=100$, $x=15$ and $x=-12$. Also, when $n=3$ and $c=1000$, $x=6$ and $x=-3$. Also again, for $n=3$, as $c \to \infty$ there also seem to be roots at $x=0$ and $x=3$. There is no limit on the domain/ range.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions. Signing off is redundant (and some consider this as unwanted noise) since there's always the gray block at the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If your equation is $$\frac{6000\,n} {x(x-n)}=c$$ multiply both sides by $x(x-n)$ and expand to get
$$6000\,n=c x^2-c n x\implies cx^2-c nx -6000n=0$$ and use the solution of the quadratic equation.

Comment: I found the solutions earlier to be: $$x= \frac{cn\pm\sqrt{c^2n^2+24000cn}}{2cn} $$
Is there any way to find all of the cases where $x$ is an integer?